# Этимология святости

Tags: этимология

Скажите, пожалуйста, какая этимология у слова "святость". Во многих словарях сказано: "отделённый, чистый, безупречный, без греха и т. д. Хотелось бы поточнее узнать!

Answer (score 1):

В славянских, балтийских и иранских языках слово «святой» (праслав. svent) происходит от индоевропейского «k'uen-to-» — возрастать, увеличиваться, цвести — в прямом и переносном смысле, плодоносить. (см. Топоров В.Н. Святость и святые в русской духовной культуре. Т.1. М.,1995, 441-442, 1995). В переводах с греческого в самых ранних старославянских текстах употребляется не калька, а свое слово; в целом же, калек в переводах богослужебных текстов с греческого на старославянский, а позже на древнерусский очень много. Это значит, как замечает там же В. Н. Топоров, что корень слова еще в дохристианскую эпоху был сакрально отмечен. «Язык сохранил слово и даже его общую семантическую идею, но существенно углубил и «спиритуализовал» по идее его содержание» (Топоров 1995: 489). В язычестве слово понималось в прямом смысле: оно означало любое возрастание, цветение, плодоношение, в Христианстве же образуется понятие «святости» как возрастания, цветения духовного. Возможно, земля свята уже потому, что она цветет и плодоносит. Люди, жители земли, становятся носителями этой святости, благодаря уже тому, что они на ней живут. Как и когда произошло переключение с языческого на христианское, с материального на духовное — неясно. Святость переносится с природы на человека, с материально-физического на идеально-духовное, с конкретного и зримого на отвлеченное и незримое, как пишет 
   http://www.pravoslavie.ru/jurnal/330.htm

В этимологическом словаре Фасмера также отмечается это значение "цветения", "процветания"  http://www.classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Vasmer-term-11765.htm

Но связь со "светом" все же, судя по всему, прослеживается: 
"СВЕТ (1) Индоевропейское – kuei(t) (свет) . Общеславянское – svetь (свет) . 
Древнерусское – св (ять) ть.

Слово «свет» в значениях «противоположность тьме, сияние, рассвет, утро» , а также «свет духовный» , «просвещение» широко употребляется с древнерусской эпохи (с XI в.) . Древнерусское слово восходит к общеславянской основе svetь и далее – к индоевропейскому корню kuei>kvei-t.

СВЯТОЙ 
Индоевропейское – k'uen-to- (святой, священный, праздничный) . Общеславянское – sve,tъjь (святой) . Старославянское – св (юс малый) тый. Древнерусское – святый. 
Слово «святой» известно с древнерусской эпохи (с XI в. ) вместе с однокоренными «свять» , «святый» , «святыни» , «святити» , с XV в. – «святость» и др. В древнерусском слово «святой» – из старославянского, где «св (юс малый) тый» восходит к общеславянскому svetъjь – «святой» . Первоисточник – индоевропейский корень k'uen > основа k'uen-to-, что значило «праздновать, святить, святой, священный» .

В современном значении «святой» – «религиозно почитаемый, божественный» .

Comment: Отец Святой. Otes- на талышском, Бог Огня. А каким должен быть Otes?
Наверное, светлым, воплощением света, добра.Это из огнищанского прошлого Роси. Санскрит- язык для перевода Вед на хинду, для дасья вообще. 
Не советовал бы использовать санскрит для перевода языка даев, роси.  Появляются вторичные значения слов. Санскрит для славян.
Если говорить о "древнерусском" языке, я бы отнес время проникновения носителей роського языка в нижнее Поволжье к 3-4 вв. до н. э.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю название идет от нашего древнего праздника "Святки", где в течение 12 дней от первой звезды («святити» др. рус.) необходимо было соблюдать пост. Возможно людей, строго соблюдавших его, в итоге и называли святыми, т.е. чистыми.